# How to display and format leading spaces (spaces at the beginning of a line) with whitespace-mode?

Tags: colors, whitespace, formatting

I want to see all spaces at the beginning of a line as dots. Also tabs and line breaks. So I've set my `init.el` file as the following:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

(setq whitespace-style '(space-mark newline-mark tab-mark))

(whitespace-mode t)

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup)

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (whitespace-mode t)))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (whitespace-mode t)))

(setq whitespace-display-mappings
  '((newline-mark 10 [172 10])
   (space-mark 32 [183] [46])))
```

And that's the result:

[image: Emacs result]

You can see the desired effect for the line breaks and the dots here, but the dots are everywhere (Eg. between the words `class` and `Lottery`). I want only the *leading spaces*, actually to mark my indentation. How can I do that?

Also, how can I format the colors? I want to select a darker dot and line break. I know it's using a display table so faces won't work, right?

Comment: For your first question: You can customize `whitespace-space-regexp` to only highlight leading spaces. See `C-h v whitespace-space-regexp` (or `M-x describe-variable ...`). The docs for `whitespace-space-regexp` contain an example of how to only highlight leading spaces.

Comment: If you wish to use `whitespace-mode`, but do not want to visualize **ALL** spaces, then comment out `space-mark` in the `whitespace-style` setting.  The doc-string for the `whitespace-style` variable contains an entry for `space-mark` that states:  "*SPACEs and HARD SPACEs are visualized via display table.*"

Comment: Closing so we can merge with a new/nearly identical question.